# My chromium version is really old

Tags: chromium, google-chrome

My chromium version is 78, but the current google chrome is 85 or something.  All my ubuntu machines's chromes are in the 80s.

But this is my chromium version:

[image]

I have tried to upgrade it using `apt`, but I am told I am already on the latest version.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
$ sudo apt-get upgrade chromium-browser
...
chromium-browser is already the newest version (78.0.3904.108-rpt1).
```

Unlike Chrome, Chromium doesn't seem to have ability to update itself.

I considered downloading chrome, but there doesn't seem to be a 32 bit version.

I could download an older chromedriver, but I wanted to find out first if there is a recommended way to install a newer chromium/chrome version, or what I am overlooking.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely not doing anything wrong. Most Linux distros don't update the official Repos immediately after an update to a package comes out. Like goldilocks mentioned, Raspbian/RpiOS is derived from Debian, which is known to update the Repos a little later than other distros. If you want you could get a fresh install of Raspibian and try if you really want to make sure you haven't done anything wrong. If you want the latest version, the [official Chromium website](https://www.chromium.org/) links to [these scripts](https://github.com/scheib/chromium-latest-linux) which you can run to get them.

Comment: *"Most Linux distros don't..."* -> Worth noting that Debian as a (de facto or de jure) policy lags behind most other distros (on the premise that this is promotes platform stability), and Raspbian/RpiOS is derived directly from it.  Hence most other distros probably do have a newer Chromium.